# How to send notifications or messages on website or to fellow website moderators using c sharp and asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently working on administrator module as m new to asp.net i am out of ideas how to implement the communication system between 
1 administrator and moderator
2 administrator announcements on website 
3 moderator sending notification to administrator .

I want to have a common panel in admin and moderator home page to see the comments,notification and announcements in different tabs . But am clueless upon what methods to apply and how to meet the requirements . I dont want to use the e mail system . 
Any suggestion will be greatly accepted .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could rely upon a handful of database table to do this job easily. 
The structure might be something like this (pardon the pseudo-language, don't have the right tool at hand to provide full SQL syntax)

```
ID (guid or identity)
TITLE (text)
TEXT (text)
TYPE (bit, 0=announcement 1=message)
FROM (foreign key to USERS)
```

alongside with a USERS table and another one to track the recipients (N:N relationship here). a "special" user meaning "this is for everyone" might prove useful here.

i'll gladly clarify and provide some proper code later if needed, but it's a simple structure you should be able to LINQToSQL your way through it easily.

Answer (score 1):

As alex suggests this could be done with a couple of database tables.

I would have a message table with: ID (int Identity), text, postedBy, recipient(0 for all users), posted date, Type(if you want to be able to categorize messages)

I assume you already will have a USERS table but if not you want to create one.

Then to get your messages you would select * from messageTable WHERE recipient = 0 OR recipient = @yourUserParameter

By implementing the Type column in the message table you can filter your messages into categories, such as System Messages, Announcements, Private Messages, etc etc.  This just makes things easier for the user and allows you to use this table to implement other features.

One consideration though is do you want messages to allow replies? In which case you would need a message_headers table and a messages table.  Your header table would contain an ID and some summary info like the date , sender, recipient etc, your messsages table would contain an id, and a parentID which links back to the message_headers ID, this table would then also contain data such as sent date/time (for ordering) senderID.